# Why is my ELB cloudwatch metrics HealthyHostCount set to 900?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have three instances running under ELB in AWS each in 3 different availability zones.  When I check the cloudwatch metrics of ELB under Per LB-metrics,  the value for HealthyHostCount is 900.

How can this be possible? have I tried to figure it out but did not find any possible solution.

Screenshot of the issue:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Can we see a screenshot?

Comment: That sounds like it could be the aggregated sum of 3 healthy instances × 300 samples.

Comment: attached the screenshot to the question @SergeyKovalev

Comment: Is the downvote is for editing the question too many times. I have edited the question couple of times to make it clear and also to add the screenshot.

Comment: Are you maybe plotting Sum statistic? Change it to Average (on the Graphed Metrics tab). If this helps you, I'll write a proper answer explaining why you need Average in this case.

Comment: awesome!! changing the statistics to Average under Graphed metrics helped. Now I wonder how sum statistics took the value to 900. could you please let me know how that value is calculated.

Comment: I think this question is worthy of a downvote too. You seem to be surprised as to the value of HealthyHostCount but do not say whether that is too high or too low. Please add to the question what value you expect, and/or why you think it is wrong.

Comment: Also, please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting a meaningful number of healthy hosts from ELB metrics you have to plot Average, Minimum or Maximum (see ELB metrics doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html)

Sum statistic is not useful for this because there are multiple factors that will affect it:

- number of hosts in the ELB.
- number of AZs ELB federates across
- frequency of health checks
- period you selected when you graphed your metric
- potentially something else I didn't think of

For ELB to determine the number of healthy hosts, it has to perform a health check. You can configure frequency of health checks in the ELB settings. ELB will publish value 1 if health check passed. So if you have health checks running every 5 seconds, you'll end up with 12 samples every minute. If you plot Sum, you will get 12 for that minute.

Further more, health checks are also done per AZ, so if you have hosts across 2 AZs number from above is 12 * 2 = 24.

On top of that, when you graph your metric, you have to select a period. In the example above you have 24 checks every minute, so if you graph with a Period of 1h, you'll get 24 * 60 = 1440.

Look at the numbers you have for the parameters mentioned above and try to see how they sum up to 900.